# Using Event Time with lateness in Flink SQL Windows

Tags: java, sql, apache-flink

I have a data stream that is generally out of order. I define the dataset as:

```
DataStream<ApplicationMetric> metrics = env
  .addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer<>("applicationMetric", new SimpleStringSchema(), consumerConfig))
  .map(mapper)
  .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<>(Time.seconds(30)));
```

And print it as:

```
Table table = bsTableEnv.fromDataStream(dataset, "createdAt, name, duration, rowtime.rowtime");
Table t1 = bsTableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT CAST((createdAt/1000) as TIMESTAMP) as ts, rowtime, name, duration " + table);
bsTableEnv.toAppendStream(t1, Row.class).print();
```

So, how would that work if I try to use it in an SQL query with time windows (tumbling etc.), is that respected? I think I might be fundementally wrong about the concepts. But I assume the late events will be just dropped and I can use my rowtime as a tumbling window attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You can control [how late events are treated](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#allowed-lateness) in Datastream API. By default all events later than 30s are dropped in your code. These 30s add to your end-to-end latency, so output is hold back until Flink has seen 30s worth of data and respected all late events. You could also store late events in a separate output or retrigger computation.

Unfortunately, there is no support for this configuration on Table API/SQL. Late events will always be dropped, but that seems to be enough for your use case.